# Firebase Crashlytics Crashing on App startup

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I am facing a very strange issue where I am getting this crash when I am trying to open the application:

```
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .      /\
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     /  \
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .    /    \
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .   / |  | \
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .     |  |
2020-08-14 08:23:42.577 27533-27533/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: .
2020-08-14 08:23:42.580 27533-27533/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ahlibank.ahlipay.subscriber.dev, PID: 27533
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:122)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.init(FirebaseCrashlytics.java:165)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.buildCrashlytics(CrashlyticsRegistrar.java:55)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar$$Lambda$1.create(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Getting no clue to solve it. I do have google.services.json in my app folder

Comment: It may be regarding its configuration integration part, some thing skipped ?

Comment: did you set `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'`?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` wouldn't apply here, because from the logs it appears they're using Firebase Crashlytics. It's likely a configuration/integration issue. @Guarav please make sure you've followed all instructions in this doc, and also update your original post with your build.gradle configuration and any other relevant parts of your code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: @KevinKokomaniYou are right I am using Firebase Crashlytics. And apply plugin io.fabric does not apply here. And yes I have already followed all the instructions for firebase setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you Omitted
(1)in your project-level build.gradle file, add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin as a buildscript dependency.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...

        // Check that you have the Google services Gradle plugin v4.3.2 or later
        // (if not, add it).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // TODO:Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }
}
```

(2) in your app-level build.gradle file, apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // Google services Gradle plugin

// TODO:Apply the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Hope it's helpful.